# Outgoing port forwarding from off-line LAN

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

A LAN network consists of two computer with static IP addresses connected with a network hub, just a dumb repeater, no DHCP. The LAN is not connected to anything else. I need one of those computers to send some data (periodic TCP connection, custom protocol) outside that LAN without exposing the LAN to access from outside. One solution would be to connect PC with two network cards, one connected to LAN with appropriate static address and other connected to WAN + some iptables magic. I am also aware that there is port forwarding on routers, where specific LAN address:port is exposed to WAN via router port. What I need is reversed concept - expose WAN address:port for outgoing connection from LAN. Does anyone know of any simpler solution?

Comment: Port forwarding might not work with your custom protocol.  A commercial-grade router can filter traffic appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... this is typically how routers and firewalls work by default. No special configuration is usually required for traffic originating internally to be allowed outbound to the internet. So... it should just work... unless you're blocking outbound traffic.